# Java HashMap: adding to arraylist

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm using the HashMap class and it looks like this:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> fileRank = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

I'm wondering how to add a new String into the Arraylist after the initial put.

```
fileRank.put(word, file1);
```

I would like to add file2 after file1 to the key: word from above.

Comment: You may also want to look into a multimap class from a 3rd party collections library.

Comment: Note: Use the interfaces as declaration types if possible:
Map<String, List<String>> fileRank = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to get the array list out first:

```
ArrayList<String> list = fileRank.get(word);
list.add(file1);
```

Of course, it becomes more complicated if you don't know whether there is an entry for that key yet.

```
ArrayList<String> list = fileRank.get(word);
if (list == null) {
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    fileRank.put(word, list);
}
list.add(file1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You ask the map for the value for a certain key, which is an ArrayList, on which you can call add.

```
String key = "myKey";
fileRank.put( key, new ArrayList<String>() );
//...
fileRank.get( key ).add( "a value");
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the `ArrayList` based on the String key, do `add()` to the ArrayList and then put it back into the `HashMap` (optional, since the map already holds the reference to it);

```
fileRank.get(word).add(String)
fileRank.put(work, list);
```

Comment: Why put it back again? Is it necessary?

Comment: You dont have to. Edited my post, thought it is more readable this way.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
public class MyContainer {

    private final Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    public void add(String key, String value) {
        if(myMap.containsKey(key)) {
            myMap.get(key).add(value);
        } else {
            ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
            newList.add(value);

            myMap.put(key, newList);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

private static HashMap> mmArrays = new HashMap>();

mmArrays.put(key,data);